# This sudoku solver not working this not able to fill empty sudoku

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I was trying to solve this sudoku question and tried this algorithm where we check every column one by one and backtrack if we get wrong answer and try with next number.

This sudoku solver is not working. This is not able to fill empty sudoku and I'm not able figure out what wrong I've done.

I've checked my solution multiple times and wrote the code again but still I'm stuck. Please help.

```
class Solution
{
  public void solveSudoku (char[][]board)
  {
    helper (board, 0, 0);
  }
  public boolean helper (char[][]board, int row, int col)
  {
    if (row == board.length)
      return true;
//next recursion row and col
    int nrow = 0;
    int ncol = 0;

    if (col == board.length - 1)
      {
    nrow = row + 1;
    ncol = 0;
      }
    else
      {
    nrow = row;
    ncol = col + 1;
      }
//if number already exist
    if (board[row][col] != '.')
      {
    if (helper (board, nrow, ncol))
      return true;
    //else check with 1 to 9 no
    else
      {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
          {
        if (isSafe (board, row, col, i))
          {
            //if number safe then set the number
            board[row][col] = (char) (i + '0');
            //and go for next col
            if (helper (board, nrow, ncol))
              return true;
            //if next recursion return false then reset this to '.'
            else
              board[row][col] = '.';

          }
          }
      }
      }
    return false;
  }

  public boolean isSafe (char[][]board, int row, int col, int n)
  {
//check with col
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
      {
    if (board[i][col] == (char) (n + '0'))
      return false;
      }
    //check row
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
      {
    if (board[row][j] == (char) (n + '0'))
      return false;
      }

    int sr = 3 * (row / 3);
    int sc = 3 * (col / 3);
//check 3*3 matrix
    for (int i = sr; i < sr + 3; i++)
      {
    for (int j = sc; j < sc + 3; j++)
      {
        if (board[i][j] == (char) (n + '0'))
          return false;

      }
      }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Your input

```
[["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]
```

Output

```
[[".",".",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]
```

Expected

```
[["5","3","4","6","7","8","9","1","2"],["6","7","2","1","9","5","3","4","8"],["1","9","8","3","4","2","5","6","7"],["8","5","9","7","6","1","4","2","3"],["4","2","6","8","5","3","7","9","1"],["7","1","3","9","2","4","8","5","6"],["9","6","1","5","3","7","2","8","4"],["2","8","7","4","1","9","6","3","5"],["3","4","5","2","8","6","1","7","9"]]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to properly format your code. Especially the inconsistent indentation makes it hard to read. Your IDE can auto-format code "in one click". Use that feature.

Comment: What does "not able to fill empty sudoku" mean? `helper()` returns false? Code runs forever?

Comment: this problem is im trying on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/sudoku-solver/    ive added my output, my code is not even filling those  '.' dots with wrong numbers and thats why im not getting whats going wrong here

Comment: i got that its first ( if (board[row][col] != '.')) in helper function is should end after checking next recursion on next row and column and else should start

Comment: i found it !  in my code
 if (board[row][col] != '.')
      {
    if (helper (board, nrow, ncol))
      return true;
    else.....
    
  right code is 
 if (board[row][col] != '.')
      {
    if (helper (board, nrow, ncol))
      return true;
      } 
      
      else......